# Thymeleaf: Delete the div that contains iterating attribute (th:each) after looping through or conditional attribute (th:if) after evaluating

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In Thymeleaf, is it possible to `delete` the `wrapper div` which contains the conditional loop? Suppose the following code in a SpringBoot application, I intend to erase the first and the second divs after evaluating the condition and looping through the errors list.

```
<div th:if="${errors != null}">
    <div th:each="error : ${errors}">
        <div th:utext="${error}"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I fancy achieving this without using JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use a `<th:block />` (which isn't rendered).  Also, no need to separate the iteration and text.  You should be able to generate the same code like this:

```
<th:block th:if="${errors != null}">
    <div th:each="error : ${errors}" th:utext="${error}" />
</th:block>
```

(I prefer `<th:block />` to `th:remove="tag"`.)

Comment: veeery interesting, what are the advantages of 'th:block' over 'th:remove="tag"'

Comment: +1 up vote for the simplified version of iteration, but don't you think the normal version is more readable (the normal version is very similar to java loop)

Comment: IMO, `th:remove` is intended more for natural templating instead of actual template functions...  I think templates should match the html as much as possible (it would be confusing to see 3 nested `div`s, when the output has no nested `div`s).  As for the java loop... I just think it's more readable this way.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is possible to delete the wrapper div with just adding the `th:remove="tag"` attribute to the desired div.

```
<div th:if="${errors != null}" th:remove="tag">
    <div th:each="error : ${errors}" th:remove="tag">
        <div th:utext="${error}"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The result of the above-mentioned code will be:

```
<div>Error 1</div>
<div>Error 2</div>
<div>Error 3</div>
<div>Error 4</div>
...
```